# Make a multilines Component() with ForEach loop ? [SwiftUI]

Tags: arrays, layout, swiftui, line-breaks

I have a loop that display all of my MyView() elements :

```
HStack() {
    ForEach(datastore.datacard) { data in
        MyView()
    }
}
```

But I want to have a maximum of 4 item MyView() per line on my screen I have a list of 10 elements and I don't want to use a ScrollView). 
I don't know, like trigger an Hstack() at each 4 elements ?

Is it possible ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a initializer for ForEach taking a Range: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach/3364099-init

```
ForEach(0..<4) { index in
    MyView()
}
```

if you need to access the data provided in `datastore.datacard` inside your ForEach you could access the data via the index:

```
ForEach(0..<(datastore.datacard.count < 4 ? datastore.datacard.count : 4)) { index in
     MyView(self.datastore.datacard[index])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to split data array into chunks using this extension:

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

then you can set the array size:

```swift
let chunksResult = datastore.datacard.chunked(into: 4)
```

For the UI Try this

```swift
VStack {
      ForEach(chunksResult) { rowData in
          HStack {
              ForEach(rowData) { columnData in
                  MyView()
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

this is the sample code and needs to be test in Xcode, I just write the code to have a clue on how you can manage it

Comment: That won't work because Array does not comform to Identifiable